# MongoDB Aggregation and table modeling

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am using MongoDB for a project that I am working on. My tables are designed as followed.

```
user = {
  id: ObjectID,
  friends: [ObjectID (user), ...]
  teams: [{
    "team_name": "example_team",
    "id": ObjectID,
    "users": [
      ObjectID (user),
      ObjectID (user),
      ....
    ]
  }]
}
```

I am trying to execute a MongoDB query in which I can find a team and return all members of the team that are friends to a given user. Would this be a suitable use case for using MongoDB aggregation? I have looked into the features of it however could not figure out how to fit it into my model. Along with that, notice how I am storing teams inside of the user. Would it be a better practice to have another table to hold users teams?

Thanks.

Comment: My impression is that you would need to use aggregation and you would end up with complicated queries. This would be an argument for separating that data as you suggested, but doing so will make querying more cumbersome. Since teams and users are a many to many relationship it is likely that your best design is to separate collections. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description - having separate collection per team is more than accurate, but if your data usage pattern gets team data/info every time when getting user info - that could affect performance (as we need to have 2nd query to get team details).

As friend is private to user, then team is a kind of shareable object.

Aggregation framework in this case (having team separate or not) is a nice solution to scan/join data based on all userIds inside a team and return it.
As this data is not very deep (we have one level - team) transformations will be easy and efficient.

Any comment welcome!